# NUnit 2.5 returns inconclusive state in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

So' I'm getting in Unit Testing. I created a really simple Function to test it.

```
    public int MultiplyByFive(int x)
    {
        return x * 5;
    }
```

The Test Method contains

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [DeploymentItem("UnitTestApp.exe")]
    public void MultiplyByFiveTest()
    {
        Program_Accessor target = new Program_Accessor(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        int x = 5; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        int expected = 25; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        int actual;
        actual = target.MultiplyByFive(x);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
    }
```

But when I run the test it returns:

[nunit http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/357576/nunit.jpg](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/357576/nunit.jpg)

"Assert.Inconclusive failed. Verify the correctness of this test method."

So what I'm doing wrong? thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NUnit 2.5 added "inconclusive" as a result state in between success and failure. [It's explained in the release notes here](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=releaseNotes&r=2.5).

NUnit is doing exactly what you told it to do. The new inconclusive state does terminate the test. If you want a message displayed in the case of your Assert failing, Assert.AreEqual() has an overload that takes a message string. Use that, and remove Assert.Inconclusive().

```
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, "Verify the correctness of this test method.");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `Assert.Inconclusive` if you are certain your test is correct  :)